# Creating Conical Polygon around multiple circular buffers?

Tags: arcpy

I have multiple circular buffers in a feature class. My goal is to create a polygon around these buffers, i.e create a conical polygon between 1 and 2 buffer, then the same with 2 & 3  and so on and finally dissolve all the borders to make a final polygon as shown in Fig2.

I tried convex hull by using minimum bounding geometry tool, but it basically covers a larger area if there are more than 2 records.It does not retain the schema and attributes.

I couldnt find any other Geoprocessing tool.I couldnt figure out how to go about it using ArcPy.

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find an out-of-the-box solution for this, though coding it wouldn't be difficult if you tried.